# Adding 2d lists together

Tags: python

I have the following output from Python:

```
x1 = [[1, 1, 6, 12, 75, 75], [2, 2, 12, 36, 225, 300], [3, 3, 24, 84, 525, 825], [4, 4, 48, 180, 1125, 1950], [5, 5, 96, 372, 2325, 4275], [6, 6, 192, 756, 2835, 7110], [7, 7, 384, 1524, 5715, 12825], [8, 8, 768, 3060, 7650, 20475]]
x2 = [[1, 2, 6, 12, 75, 75], [2, 3, 12, 36, 225, 300], [3, 4, 24, 84, 525, 825], [4, 5, 48, 180, 1125, 1950], [5, 6, 96, 372, 2325, 4275], [6, 7, 192, 756, 2835, 7110]]
x3 = [[1, 3, 6, 12, 75, 75], [2, 4, 12, 36, 225, 300], [3, 5, 24, 84, 525, 825], [4, 6, 48, 180, 1125, 1950], [5, 7, 96, 372, 2325, 4275]]
x4 = [[1, 4, 6, 12, 75, 75], [2, 5, 12, 36, 225, 300], [3, 6, 24, 84, 525, 825], [4, 7, 48, 180, 1125, 1950]]
```

Basically I want to add these lists by matching up the second number in each (this second number represents a month, whereas the other numbers following it represent members or profit).

So if we look at lists `x1` and `x2`, I would want to join `x1[1]` and `x2[0]` together because they both are equal at the second element (i.e. `x1[1][1]` and `x2[0][1]`).

By joining together I mean I would like to add them. Ideally I would prefer to only add the 3rd through 6 elements together.

Comment: I still have no idea what you're looking for after reading your description. Could you show the expected result for the given numbers?

Comment: Basically I want to match up lists where the second element is the same and then add all the numbers together. So x1+x2 would result in [2, 2, 12, 36, 225, 300] (x1[1]) being added to [1, 2, 6, 12, 75, 75] (x2[0]). This would result in [3, 4, 18,48, 300, 375]. Continuing the trend we would then add [3,3,24,84, 525, 825] (x1[2]) and [2,3,12,36,225,300] (x2[1]) together which would make [5, 6, 36, 96, 750, 1125].

Comment: This should be easier to read:  Basically I want to match up lists where the second element is the same and then add all the numbers together. So x1+x2 would result in *[2, 2, 12, 36, 225, 300]* (x1[1]) being added to *[1, 2, 6, 12, 75, 75]* (x2[0]). This would result in **[3, 4, 18,48, 300, 375]**. Continuing the trend we would then add *[3,3,24,84, 525, 825]* (x1[2]) and *[2,3,12,36,225,300]* (x2[1]) together which would make **[5, 6, 36, 96, 750, 1125]**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out using  [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [slicing lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).  That basically will let you turn:

> I would prefer to only add the 3rd through 6 elements together.

into exactly what you want to do. To do the combining of lists, you might try creating a dict and them sum together at the end.  I'm not 100% clear on what your expected output should be from that whole list and it's somewhat dependent on other things going on in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Currently I am thinking of taking out the first element from the list permanently, as it's kind of useless. Then when I add the lists together I would only need to preserve the new first element, which refers to months.  I was thinking I could have the months value as a key in a dictionary, and then have the list as the value?  So x1 = {1, [list], 2 [list] ...}  However I would be unsure how to match up the dictionaries and add them. This would give me better code I think but still leave me where I was before.